# replace dashes with guessed letter in java

Tags: java

really beginner javascript user here, creating a hangman game. i am having the world of difficulty in trying to show a users correct guess. 
from my understanding i have only masked the secret word with dashes so therefor am trying to make it become unmasked when a correct letter is guessed. 
i imagine i need to use charAt somewhere, somehow but to be honest i just cant figure it out.

My code is still very basic and i havent done much else as there isnt much point writing out the rest of the game if you cant see the guess but here is the code i have so far... please remember this is still a very unfinished project.

```
 package hangmangame;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Matt
 */
public class HangmanGame {


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    char letter = 0; //declares and initailise letter
    String marks = ""; //declares and initailise string for dashes
    String [] words = { "gluttony", "lust", "greed", "pride", "despair", "wrath", "vainglory", "rhythm", "delicious", "better", "jacuzzi" , "ironman", "captainamerica", "thor", "hulk", "spiderman", "antman", "batman"}; //declares and initailise array of words to guess
    String word = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)]; //chooses random word from the word array
    for (int i=1;i<=word.length(); i++) // for method for displaying the correct word as dashes
    {
        marks += "-"; //dashes to represent the correct word.
    }



        System.out.println("lets play hangman, your word is " + marks + "\n" + "enter a letter to guess the word");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        letter = input.next(".").charAt(0); //assign inputted letter to letter variable

     if ((word).contains(""+letter)) //if statement to excute if guessed letter is in word

         // i imagine this is where i put some sort of code to show that guessed letter?

         System.out.println("You guessed a letter!" + marks); //display for correct letter
```

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started. It's important to grab the entire line from the user instead of using next()... Unless you are an experienced coder and understand the way in which the next() iterates over the input I'd highly suggest using nextLine() as it's much easier to use.

```
        char letter = 0; //declares and initailise letter
        String [] words = { "gluttony", "lust", "greed", "pride", "despair", "wrath", "vainglory", "rhythm", "delicious", "better", "jacuzzi" , "ironman", "captainamerica", "thor", "hulk", "spiderman", "antman", "batman"}; //declares and initailise array of words to guess
        String word = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)]; //chooses random word from the word array
        String [] marks = new String[word.length()];
        for (int i=0;i<word.length(); i++) // for method for displaying the correct word as dashes
        {
            marks[i] = "-"; //dashes to represent the correct word.
        }

        HashSet<Character> lettersGuessed = new HashSet<>(); //keep track of letters guessed
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = "";
        String currentWord = "";

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Word is - ");
            currentWord = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(marks[i]);
            }

            System.out.print("\nGuess a letter - ");
            userInput = input.nextLine(); //always grab lines
            if(userInput.length() != 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid guess - " + userInput);
            }
            else if(lettersGuessed.contains(userInput.charAt(0)))
            {
                System.out.println("You already guess that character - " + userInput);
            }
            else if(word.contains(userInput))
            {
                lettersGuessed.add(userInput.charAt(0));
                currentWord = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
                {
                    if(word.charAt(i) == userInput.charAt(0))
                    {
                        marks[i] = "" + userInput.charAt(0);
                    }
                    currentWord += marks[i];
                }
            }

            if(currentWord.equals(word))
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("You guessed it! The word was " + word + "!");
```

Output

```
Word is - ----
Guess a letter - l
Word is - --l-
Guess a letter - h
Word is - h-l-
Guess a letter - l
You already guess that character - l
Word is - h-l-
Guess a letter - u
Word is - hul-
Guess a letter - tg
Invalid guess - tg
Word is - hul-
Guess a letter - k
You guessed it! The word was hulk!
```

Comment: Sorry to bother on a really old thread/comment. This is a really nice answer and helped me with my own hangman project - I was just wondering what the difference in square vs circle brackets were? (e.g. you have "marks[i]" in some places and other places you have the normal (i) syntax). My guess would be it having something to do with global loop vs local loop but I don't know?

Comment: @HarveyRael I appreciate the compliment. As for your question, are you referring to lines where the array marks[] is being accessed and when we use the function word.charAt(i)? If so, remember that square brakcets is because we are accessing an array directly, and the parentheses in charAt() is because we are accessing a function/method. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

the String class contains an `indexOf(String c)` method which returns the index of the first occurrence of a substring. For example, if `word` was `delicious` then `word.indexOf("i")` would return `3`, the first index of the substring `"i"`.

But what about all other occurences of the substring `"i"`? Well, the `indexOf` method is handily overwritten to help with that. There is another version of it, `indexOf(String ch, int fromIndex)` that takes in a starting index. Continuing our earlier example, if you asked for `word.indexOf("i", 4)` this time you would get back `5`, the first index of the substring `"i"` in the string `"delicious"` if we are discounting every index before the fourth one.

Think of it this way, indexOf is kind of the opposite of charAt. charAt takes in an index and gives you a character, indexOf takes in a character or string and gives you its first index.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would all be a lot easier if you stored the word and the marks as character arrays like this:

```
char letter = 0; //declares and initailise letter
String [] words = { "gluttony", "lust", "greed", "pride", "despair", "wrath", "vainglory", "rhythm", "delicious", "better", "jacuzzi" , "ironman", "captainamerica", "thor", "hulk", "spiderman", "antman", "batman"}; //declares and initailise array of words to guess
String word = words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)]; //chooses random word from the word array
char[] chosenWord = new char[word.length()];
char[] marks = new char[word.length];
for (int i=0;i< word.length(); i++) // for method for displaying the correct word as dashes
{
    chosenWord[i] = word.charAt(i);
    marks[i] = '-';
}



    System.out.println("lets play hangman, your word is " + new String(marks) + "\n" + "enter a letter to guess the word");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    letter = input.next(".").charAt(0); //assign inputted letter to letter variable

 if ((word).contains(""+letter)){ //if statement to excute if guessed letter is in word
      for(int i =0; i < chosenWord.length; i++){
            if(chosenWord[i] == letter){
                    marks[i] = chosenWord[i]
            }
      } 
     // i imagine this is where i put some sort of code to show that guessed letter?

     System.out.println("You guessed a letter!" + new String(marks));
}
```

I didn't syntax check this, but you should get the idea of what I'm working at.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i made.
I think its much better to use arrays here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"gluttony", "lust", "greed", "pride", "despair", "wrath", "vainglory", "rhythm", "delicious", "better", "jacuzzi", "ironman", "captainamerica", "thor", "hulk", "spiderman", "antman", "batman"}; //declares and initailise array of words to guess
    String word[] = (words[(int) (Math.random() * words.length)]).split(""); //chooses random word from the word array and creates a array of letters
    String[] marks = new String[word.length];
    Arrays.fill(marks,"-"); // creates and fills an array with dashes
    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letter = "";
    int counter = 0;
    while(Arrays.toString(marks).contains("-")) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("This is your word!: " + String.join("", marks));
        System.out.print("Guess a letter ");
        letter = String.valueOf(in.next(".").charAt(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if(word[i].equals(letter)){
                marks[i] = word[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Congratulations your word is " + String.join("",marks) + "You did it in " + counter + "trials");
}
```

}